Yet another percentage question in SQL / redshift
Here is where I am now....
table1 looks like this (yes like most posts here, this is a gross simplification of the actual tables)



userID
type




12345
small


67893
medium


32389
small


88733
medium


23580
medium



table2 looks like this



userID
randomunimportantdata




12345
random1


32389
random2


88733
random3



for clarification, table1 has many more userid than table2, table2 is a subset of table1.
my goal is to determine,

how many of each userid from table2 there are for a given type in table1, where I show the ColumnA is the type,
ColumnB is the total userid that match that type from table2,
ColumnC is the total sum of the userid in table1 per type, and
columnD is calculated as ColumnB divided by ColumnC.

The ultimate output should look like this:



type
type_count
total_type_count
percent_penetration




small
1202
1900
63.xx%


medium
674
873
77.xx%



I have gotten this far:
select type, count(*) as type_count
from table1
where userid in (
    select distinct owner as userid
    from table2
)
and report_date = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
group by type
order by type_count desc;

this generates a table that looks like this



type
type_count




small
1202


medium
674



My work so far gets me most of the way to what I need, but still requires some manual work afterwards, which I am trying to resolve as it will not scale.
I am looking for some guidance on how to make the last mile.
Thanks in advance

Can you add some data in input table and simplify your output table result: type | type_count | total_type_count | percent_penetration according to your input table

Your current output table type | type_count | total_type_count | percent_penetration confusing more to design query

You could improve this question by including representative sample data , output that would derive from that sample and making the sample and query consistent (there is no owner in the published sample)

I think you wan't something like
select type, count(b.userid) as type_count, count(a.userid) as total_type_count, (100.0 * count(b.userid)) /  count(a.userid) as  percent_penetration
from table1 a left join table2 b on a.userid = b.userid
where report_date = 'yyyy-mm-dd'
group by type
order by type_count desc;

count(fieldname) counts only nonnull values and b.userid is null when there is no record in table2 through the left join...
